# How to put a text like this pattern? (different size, style)

Tags: fonts

It is difficult to explain what I want so I found this text and I planning to make a small book that containts, quotes and some poetry so I thought it will be nice to have this kind of text, not to messy but with different styles

[image: like this]

I found this package
http://mirror.math.ku.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/verse/verse.pdf
you can see on page 14 one example that I like

Comment: Using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and [fontspec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) you can use all fonts installed on your system. Especially OpenType fonts might be of interest for you.

Comment: This will be easier to do if you use `fontspec` with either the XeTeX or LuaTeX engines.  But you have to find the fonts you want to use first.  The various 'verse'-related packages will be good for unusual newline indentation patterns.

Comment: Not at all related, but reminded me of: http://www-958.ibm.com/software/data/cognos/manyeyes/page/Word_Cloud_Generator.html

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, my fonts were only approximate (most people will not have these fonts).  Furthermore, they could not be rendered in all sizes, and so I often had to resort to `\scalebox`es instead of font sizes to obtain the proper size.  Clearly, this is a 1st cut just to demonstrate the possibility.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\AdineKirnberg}[1][]{\fontfamily{AdineKirnberg}#1\selectfont}
\newcommand{\CaslonAntique}[1][]{\fontfamily{CaslonAntique}#1\selectfont}
\newcommand{\CaslonAntiquei}[1][]{\fontfamily{CaslonAntique}\fontshape{it}#1\selectfont}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\BL{\color{red!10!green!40!blue!80}}
\def\RD{\color{black!20!red}}
\def\GR{\color{black!10!gray}}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{red!40!green!50!gray!20}
\CaslonAntique
\stackunder[-22pt]{%
\stackunder{%
\stackunder[-9pt]{%
\stackunder[1pt]{%
\stackunder[-1pt]{%
\stackunder[-10.5pt]{%
\stackunder[-5pt]{%
\stackunder[-12pt]{%
  {\CaslonAntiquei\Huge\scalebox{1.3}{\raisebox{-12pt}{\GR``}}} sometimes you~~}%
{~\scalebox{1.5}{\LARGE \BL READ}}%
}{~~~~a book so {\AdineKirnberg\scalebox{3}{\Large \raisebox{-1.3pt}{\RD special}}}}%
}{that you~~ want to}%
}{\Large ~~~{\BL CARRY} {\normalsize it} {\BL AROUND}}%
}{~~~~~~~~~with you for ~~~~after you've}%
}{\AdineKirnberg \scalebox{3.5}{\Large\RD  months~~~}}%
}{finished just to ~~~~~~~~~~~~~{\CaslonAntiquei\Huge\scalebox{1.3}{\raisebox{-12pt}{\GR ''}}}}%
}{{\scalebox{1.5}{\Large ~~~~~~~~~~\BL STAY}} near it}%

\vspace{2ex}
\hspace{.9in}\scalebox{.7}{-Markus Zusak}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To compile with default LaTeX fonts, here's a version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\AdineKirnberg}[1][]{\itshape}%
\newcommand{\CaslonAntique}[1][]{}%
\newcommand{\CaslonAntiquei}[1][]{}%
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\BL{\color{red!10!green!40!blue!80}}
\def\RD{\color{black!20!red}}
\def\GR{\color{black!10!gray}}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{red!40!green!50!gray!20}
\CaslonAntique
\stackunder[-22pt]{%
\stackunder{%
\stackunder[-8.5pt]{%
\stackunder[1pt]{%
\stackunder[.3pt]{%
\stackunder[-8.7pt]{%
\stackunder[-8pt]{%
\stackunder[-12pt]{%
  {\CaslonAntiquei\Huge\scalebox{1.3}{\raisebox{-12pt}{\GR``}}} sometimes you~~}%
{~\scalebox{1.5}{\LARGE \BL READ}}%
}{~~~~a book so {\AdineKirnberg\scalebox{3}{\Large \raisebox{-1.3pt}{\RD special}}}~}%
}{that you~~ want to~~~~~~~}%
}{\Large ~~~{\BL CARRY} {\normalsize it} {\BL AROUND~~~~}}%
}{~~~~~~~~~with you for ~~~~~~~after you've~~}%
}{\AdineKirnberg \scalebox{3.5}{\Large\RD  months~~~}}%
}{finished just to ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~{\CaslonAntiquei\Huge\scalebox{1.3}{\raisebox{-12pt}{\GR ''~~~}}}}%
}{{\scalebox{1.5}{\Large ~~~~~~~~~~\BL STAY}} near it~~~~~}%

\vspace{2ex}
\hspace{.9in}\scalebox{.7}{-Markus Zusak}
\end{document}
```

[image]